# Connection issues with TI CC3000 & Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

I bought a CC3000 Wifi Shield from Sparkfun and attached it to Arduino Uno board.

As first thing I tested the board with the board test example:

> SparkFun CC3000 - Board Test
>
> CC3000 initialization complete
>
> Firmware version: 1.24
>
> MAC address: 70:FF:76:01:30:1E
>
> Finished board test

---

Then I scanned the networks:

> SparkFun CC3000 - Scan Test
>
> CC3000 initialization complete
>
> Scanning APs. Waiting for scan to complete.
>
> Access Points found:
>
> SSID: dnhm MAC address: 20:AA:4B:08:AA:CC RSSI: 58 Security: WPA2
>
> SSID: dnhm-guest MAC address: 20:AA:4B:08:AA:CE RSSI: 58 Security: Unsecured
>
> Finished scan test

---

I set the SSID and the password and tried to connect:

> SparkFun CC3000 - Connection Test
>
> CC3000 initialization complete
>
> Connecting to: dnhm
>
> Error: Could not connect to AP
>
> Error: Could not obtain connection details
>
> Error: Could not disconnect from network Finished connection test

---

> SparkFun CC3000 - Connection Test
>
> CC3000 initialization complete Connecting to: dnhm-guest
>
> Error: Could not connect to AP
>
> Error: Could not obtain connection details
>
> Error: Could not disconnect from network
>
> Finished connection test

It did not connect none of the available connections, I reserved an IP address on the router for the mac address, but nothing changed.

I turned on logs on the router (Linksys e2500) and nothing appeared in logs as if the device never tried to connect. (I can see relevant logs when I re-connect with my notebook)

I use wpa2 so I kept the security setting as it is. I also have a 5ghz SSID and it does not show up in the scan. So I did not try to connect to it.

I also tried the smart config example with my ipad and it did not work either, the output:

> SparkFun CC3000 - SmartConfig
>
> CC3000 initialization complete
>
> Starting SmartConfig
>
> Send connection details from app now!
>
> Waiting to connect…
>
> Error: Could not connect with SmartConfig
>
> Error: Could not obtain connection details
>
> Looking up IP address of: www.sparkfun.com
>
> Error: Could not lookup host by name
>
> Pinging 0.0.0.0 3 times…
>
> Error: no ping response
>
> Error: Could not disconnect from network
>
> Finished SmartConfig test

Obviously the board works (It can scan/find the networks), but cant connect them. What should I do as next step to troubleshoot the issue?

Here is the sample I used for connection testing: (I double checked the protocol from router's wifi settings to make sure I'm using the correct one)

```
    /****************************************************************
ConnectionTest.ino
CC3000 Connection Test
Shawn Hymel @ SparkFun Electronics
January 30, 2014
https://github.com/sparkfun/SFE_CC3000_Library

Connects to the access point given by the SSID and password and
waits for a DHCP-assigned IP address. To use a static IP
address, change the #define USE_DHCP from 1 to 0 and assign an
IP address to static_ip_addr in the Constants section.

NOTE: Static IP is not working at this time.

The security mode is defined by one of the following:
WLAN_SEC_UNSEC, WLAN_SEC_WEP, WLAN_SEC_WPA, WLAN_SEC_WPA2

Hardware Connections:

 Uno Pin    CC3000 Board    Function

 +5V        VCC or +5V      5V
 GND        GND             GND
 2          INT             Interrupt
 7          EN              WiFi Enable
 10         CS              SPI Chip Select
 11         MOSI            SPI MOSI
 12         MISO            SPI MISO
 13         SCK             SPI Clock

Resources:
Include SPI.h and SFE_CC3000.h

Development environment specifics:
Written in Arduino 1.0.5
Tested with Arduino UNO R3

This code is beerware; if you see me (or any other SparkFun 
employee) at the local, and you've found our code helpful, please
buy us a round!

Distributed as-is; no warranty is given.
****************************************************************/

#include <SPI.h>
#include <SFE_CC3000.h>

// Pins
#define CC3000_INT      2   // Needs to be an interrupt pin (D2/D3)
#define CC3000_EN       7   // Can be any digital pin
#define CC3000_CS       10  // Preferred is pin 10 on Uno

// IP address assignment method
#define USE_DHCP        1   // 0 = static IP, 1 = DHCP

// Connection info data lengths
#define IP_ADDR_LEN     4   // Length of IP address in bytes
#define MAC_ADDR_LEN    6   // Length of MAC address in bytes

// Constants
char ap_ssid[] = "SSID";                  // SSID of network
char ap_password[] = "PASSWORD";          // Password of network
unsigned int ap_security = WLAN_SEC_WPA2; // Security of network
unsigned int timeout = 30000;             // Milliseconds
//const char static_ip_addr[] = "0.0.0.0";

// Global Variables
SFE_CC3000 wifi = SFE_CC3000(CC3000_INT, CC3000_EN, CC3000_CS);

void setup() {

    ConnectionInfo connection_info;
    int i;

    // Initialize Serial port
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("---------------------------------");
    Serial.println("SparkFun CC3000 - Connection Test");
    Serial.println("---------------------------------");

    // Initialize CC3000 (configure SPI communications)
    if ( wifi.init() ) {
        Serial.println("CC3000 initialization complete");
    } else {
        Serial.println("Something went wrong during CC3000 init!");
    }

#if (USE_DHCP == 1)
    // Connect using DHCP
    Serial.print("Connecting to: ");
    Serial.println(ap_ssid);
    if(!wifi.connect(ap_ssid, ap_security, ap_password, timeout)) {
        Serial.println("Error: Could not connect to AP");
    }
#elif (USE_DHCP == 0)
    // Connect using static IP
    // ***TODO: Connect using static IP
#endif

    // Print out connection details
    if( !wifi.getConnectionInfo(connection_info) ) {
        Serial.println("Error: Could not obtain connection details");
    } else {
        Serial.println("Connected!");
        Serial.println();

        // Print MAC address
        Serial.print("CC3000 MAC Address: ");
        for ( i = 0; i < MAC_ADDR_LEN; i++ ) {
            if ( connection_info.mac_address[i] < 0x10 ) {
                Serial.print("0");
            }
            Serial.print(connection_info.mac_address[i], HEX);
            if ( i < MAC_ADDR_LEN - 1 ) {
                Serial.print(":");
            }
        }
        Serial.println();

        // Print IP Address
        Serial.print("IP Address: ");
        printIPAddr(connection_info.ip_address);
        Serial.println();

        // Print subnet mask
        Serial.print("Subnet Mask: ");
        printIPAddr(connection_info.subnet_mask);
        Serial.println();

        // Print default gateway
        Serial.print("Default Gateway: ");
        printIPAddr(connection_info.default_gateway);
        Serial.println();

        // Print DHCP server address
        Serial.print("DHCP Server: ");
        printIPAddr(connection_info.dhcp_server);
        Serial.println();

        // Print DNS server address
        Serial.print("DNS Server: ");
        printIPAddr(connection_info.dns_server);
        Serial.println();

        // Print SSID
        Serial.print("SSID: ");
        Serial.println(connection_info.ssid);
        Serial.println();
    }

    // Disconnect
    if ( wifi.disconnect() ) {
        Serial.println("Disconnected");
    } else {
        Serial.println("Error: Could not disconnect from network");
    }

    // Done!
    Serial.println("Finished connection test");

}

void loop() {

    // Do nothing
    delay(1000);

}

// Print out an IP Address in human-readable format
void printIPAddr(unsigned char ip_addr[]) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < IP_ADDR_LEN; i++) {
        Serial.print(ip_addr[i]);
        if ( i < IP_ADDR_LEN - 1 ) {
            Serial.print(".");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your sketch code? Also, are you setting the proper security mode, for the Connection Test Examples?

Comment: I added the source code into the question, it s the sample that comes with the library. I just replaced SSID and the password. I also checked & verified the security mode from router settings.